# How to make jQuery Grid with grouping multiple column - PHP ?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

How could I generate a jquery grid with grouping on multiple columns?

The below is the code I am using and I need to group the grid with multiple column names. Currently it is being grouped with a single column.

The select menu for the columns names are coming in drop down menu.

This is the jQuery code for grouping the grid using the selected menu item:

```
<script>
        jQuery("#chngroup").change(function()
        {
            var vl = jQuery(this).val(); 
            if(vl) 
            { 
                if(vl == "clear") 
                    jQuery("#<?php echo $grid_id ?>").jqGrid('groupingRemove',true); 
                else 
                    jQuery("#<?php echo $grid_id ?>").jqGrid('groupingGroupBy',vl); 
            } 
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Before setting a bounty, you should ask a question…

Comment: this is a question. I wanted to know the process of developing a code for multiple grid with jquery!!

Comment: Well, nobody would give an exact step-by-step instruction; you should tell us, what is your problem during that process.

Comment: actually i am using a grid with grouping on a single column at a time and instead that i need to have multiple columns to be grouped on.

Answer (score 1):

To group on multiple columns, you need to pass all the columns names to the `groupingGroupBy` method as an array (the first value in the array is the first level, the second value is the second level and etc.).

For example lets say that you want to group first by *name* and then *date* columns:

```
 jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', ['name', 'date']);
```

This should do the trick. You can pass all the other `groupingView` options in an additional parameter (as na object which will be used to extend default `groupingView`).

**UPDATE**

I have created a live example on jsFiddle -> [jqGrid multigrouping with 'groupingGroupBy' method](http://jsfiddle.net/tpeczek/pfyuS/)

Comment: @HarsimranSingh Please check which version fo jqGrid you are using, multigrouping support is available since jqGrid 4.4.0

Comment: @HarsimranSingh Please visit the link in update to see working example.

Comment: I think the OP wants to group by multiple columns on 1 level rather than group by 1 column and have multiple levels